# Select rows where values in two columns not matching the request

Tags: mysql, sql, select, rows

I need to select all rows where value not matching on two columns

```
name  |  surname
John  |   Smith
John  |   Colch
John  |   Rak
Emmy  |   Oppo
John  |   Oppo
```

How can I select all the rows where name Name!=John and Surname!=Opp , so it would return everything except of last entry because when I try

```
Select * from t where name!='john' and surname!='oppo'
```

Then I'm loosing Emmy as she has the same surname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you actually want `OR` logic here:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE name <> 'John' OR surname <> 'Oppo';
```